# <TextInput keyboardType="numeric"/> is not working in react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

> Here is my instance

```
var LoginPopup=React.createClass({
   render:function(){
            return(
               <View>
                   <TextInput placeholder="number" keyboardType="numeric"/>
 <TextInput placeholder="url" keyboardType="url"/>

               </View>
            )

  }
})
```

> In this component any type of keyboardType is not working(like
>   number,url, email-address,number-pad,phone-pad etc ,)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is the component not visible? Or the keyboard is not numeric?

Comment: I am facing same problem in android. @Chirag - I think 'vasavi' is referring to a problem that - keyboardType="numeric" opens up the keyboard which has characters too. Ideally it should open a keyboard with numbers only. We have such keyboard in android.

Comment: @C.P. No, Android doesn't have a keyboard like that.  Android doesn't have a keyboard at all.  The keyboard is a separate app that's different for each model of phone (or can  be replaced by the user), and depending on the model of phone it may or may not have a numeric only screen.  There's no requirement for it.  Nor is there a requirement that a given keyboard app honor the inputType being set to numeric.

Answer (score 8):

```
<TextInput value={this.state.mobileNumber}
     returnKeyType={'next'}
     keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
     onChangeText={(mobileNumber) => this.setState({mobileNumber})}
                                       style={[styles.input]}                                      
  />
```

Comment: it doesn't show 'next' key in ios when key board type is numeric or phone-pad

Comment: on ios you have to use 'done' ```returnKeyType: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'done' : 'next',```

Comment: it doesn't show the dot, comma in android

Answer (score 4):

`keyboardType="numeric"` does work for me on react-native `0.46.3` on both **Android** and **iOS**.
Are you sure using an *alphabetical* placeholder ("number") is not the cause of the issue?

This is my relevant code:

```
<TextInput
    editable={!this.state.user.logged}
    onChangeText={(mobileNumber) => this.setState({mobileNumber})}
    placeholder={I18n.t('MobileNumber')}
    ref='mobileNumber'
    returnKeyType={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'done' : 'next'}
    placeholder={I18n.t('MobileNumber')}
    style={styles.inputText}
    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    value={this.state.mobileNumber}
    keyboardType="numeric"
/>
```

Comment: Uh, why should placeholder affect the keyboard in any way?

Comment: I just suppose a string value could change the type of the TextInput...

Answer (score 2):

its working for me
keyboardType='numeric'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **onChangeText** for it to work

```
<TextInput placeholder="number" keyboardType="numeric" onChangeText={() => { }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the prop inputMode="numeric" and inputMode="url" as follows:

```
<TextInput placeholder="number" keyboardType="numeric" inputMode="numeric"/>
<TextInput placeholder="url" keyboardType="url" inputMode="url"/>
```

Answer (score -6):

Maybe it will work:

```
keyboardType={"numeric"}
```